# Serial Number in PHP-MySQL Pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I am using simple PHP-MySQL pagination and I use serial number for my records. for this purpose I use the following code,

```
$serial = 1;
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT $limit");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
$s_num = $serial++;
$name = $row['name'];
echo $s_num . $name."<br>";
}
```

Now the problem is that the serial number start from 1 in every page in my pagination while i need it from 11-20 in 2nd page, from 21-30 in 3rd page and so on.

Comment: You need to add (current page)*$limit value to 
$s_num

Answer (score 1):

add a `$page` var get it from `$_GET`.

```
$serial = ($page * $limit) + 1;
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT ".($page * $limit).", $limit");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $s_num = $serial++;
    $name = $row['name'];
    echo $s_num . $name."<br>";
}
```

This is correct but the variable page.should be start from 0.... Other wise the serial number start from 11....

Answer (score 0):

add a `$page` var, get it from `$_GET`.

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
if (!$page) $page = 0;
else $page--; //first page become 0 instead of 1
$serial = ($page * $limit) + 1;
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT ".($page * $limit).", $limit");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $s_num = $serial++;
    $name = $row['name'];
    echo $s_num . $name."<br>";
}
```